# Object variable vs setter and getter

Tags: java, object

I would like to ask you: below is class Student, very easy and then below 
    main method. First by example second by me.

```
public class Student{

private String name;
private int age;

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge(){
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age){
    this.age = age;
}


}
```

And here is main method. I don´t unerstand why making it more complicated. I get the same resultes by using it with my example.

example no.1

```
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Student johnReferenceVariable = getStudent("John",25);
    System.out.println("Name : = "+johnReferenceVariable.getName());
    System.out.println("Age  : = "+johnReferenceVariable.getAge());


}


public static Student getStudent(String name, int age){
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setName(name);
    student.setAge(age);
    return student; 
}
}
```

My example of Main class and method:

```
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Student johnReferenceVariable = getStudent("John",25);
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setName("Martin");
    student.setAge(25);
    System.out.println("Name : = "+student.getName());
    System.out.println("Age : = "+student.getAge());

    //System.out.println("Name : = "+johnReferenceVariable.getName());
    //System.out.println("Age  : = "+johnReferenceVariable.getAge());


}


//public static Student getStudent(String name, int age){
    //Student student = new Student();
   // student.setName(name);
    //student.setAge(age);
    //return student; 
//}
}
```

Thank you much

Comment: Please always include the language tag that you're using, I've added java for you.

Comment: do you actually think there is any sense in the "vs" you put in the title of your question? if so, you haven't understood the base concepts.

Comment: So this is why I am asking. Is it another way of setting up variables by object type?

Comment: you can have a constructor which takes in name and age

Comment: It is not making it complicated. It is just another way of accomplishing a task. I guess it can be called as diversity in tech.

Comment: ok, thank you nimi0112

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that these two lines don't compile:

```
System.out.println("Name : = "+student.getName());
System.out.println("Age : = "+student.getAge());
```

`student` is not in scope.

I suppose your question is:

> Why should I create a method when I can just write the body of the method?

If you make a method like this:

```
public static Student getStudent(String name, int age){
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setName(name);
    student.setAge(age);
    return student; 
}
```

you are adding a layer of abstraction. Instead of saying:

```
Student student = new Student();
student.setName("Tom");
student.setAge(10);
```

which is less abstract, you say:

```
getStudent("Tom", 10);
```

which is more abstract.

Abstraction is good, it allows you, and other programmers, to not have to think about what is happening in full detail all the time. When you read your code, sometimes you don't want to know (or you do know already) how your program "gets a student". You may just want to see what your code does on a high level of abstraction.

In this case, your example is too small-scale for this to have an effect. When you are writing much longer methods, you will find the need of extracting some parts of it as methods. This way you don't have to read code at a low level abstraction all the time.

Comment: Waw, thank you Sweeper, I would tick this aswer as useful but I don´t have enough points so at least this way :-)

Answer (score 2):

They're equivalent.

If you want to make it more object-oriented you should create a two argument constructor. Than your object declaration would look like `Student student = new Student("Max", 23);`.

Comment: how is that 'more object-oriented'? it's a different approach, but calling instance methods on instances is pretty OO on itself.

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario 1:**

In the first example, you are passing only required data to the constructor, which is the case when you need to provide some default application data to be set in your Object.

Consider a Bank account opening application. In that application, you only pass required data like name, address and phone into the constructor.

Inside the constructor, the application itself provides the extra data to your account object like Bank A/C no, Card no, ATM CARD pin and so on.

```
BankAccount(String name){
//providing AUTO GENERATED BANK A/C Number and ATM PIN
}
```

**Scenario 2:**

In case 2, you yourself setting all the data. So at the time of object creating you must know all the details, in this scenario, no default or auto-generated data will be provided to your Object.

Comment: Aha, great explanation, thank you Mehraj.

Answer (score 0):

Both are almost equivalent.

The only difference is that in example 1 the `getStudent` method can be reused in Main's other methods.

Extracting code snippets into reusable methods, reusable classes and reusable  modules helps to build good software and avoid the creation of [GOD objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

Comment: I am just in the 1/3 of JAVA master class course and I have deep in memory to use getters and setters to set up values and get it back. But with another capitol for me where you set up method of return type class and then you have to make object it is for begginer like me quite confusing :-)

Comment: @Domorodec what do you mean by 'JAVA master class course'?

Comment: It is on-line course of learning JAVA from the complete basic things up to database and more complicated stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the proper code to a new method makes your code much easier to read, and the method can be reused later, I suggest you should take a look at some java refactor examples and maybe martin fowler's Refactoring book.

Comment: Ok Azarea, I will search cause I will not move forward without understanding this logic.

Answer (score 0):

Using the factory method getStudent() is a design pattern that hides the call to new.  By doing so, the code can be changed to log, query a database, or even return a subclass of student.

This can be done without modifying the calling code, which leads to better decoupling of components.

It would be even more flexable, but more complicated, if the method returned an interface instead of a class.

So to answer the question, the complexity creates flexability.